# Plot Data Frame Value using Row Names as x - error (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, plot, pca

I am new to the community and to R and I sincerely ask for your indulgence regarding the level of my question.

I am currently doing trying to do a PCA analysis using R. 
The data concerns Swap Rates and I would like to plot the loading factors against the Principal components using the results from the `Prcomp` function.

I tried to plot the results of the `Prcomp` function directly and to convert the loadings factor table into a data frame before plotting, but neither case worked. I keep getting errors like: `(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` or simply graphs that do not reflect what I trying to do.

I attached a screenshot of the structure of the dataframe [image: dataframe]

Comment: I think you are looking for. `biplot(x)` where x is object of class prcomp.

Comment: Welcome to SO community. Refer this post to convey question better. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)